# How to implement a neural network in tensorflow with multiple right solutions

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to code a CNN with tensorflow in order to play poker.
The state of the game is the input a 9x17x17 tensor, the output should be 10 values in between 0 and 1 and the highest should then be determined as my move.
To train this network I prepared samples with the state, but I don't have the kind of labels which I used so far as for example in the MNIST dataset. Instead I got basically a list with 1 entry for each output containing the normalized win/loss scenario. 0-0.5 means loss, where 0 means all chips were lost and 0.5-1 means win with 1 meaning that all chips were won.
In order to test if my network is working I created game states against one all-in bot.
The output of my network might be something like this:
[0.322, 0.5553, 0.003, 0.773, 0.123, 0.444, 0.122, 0.888, 0.921, 0.232]
Each entry represents one respective move.
The actual game results (vs the all-in player) are something like this:
[0.475 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

My idea for the cost function was to simply use the maximum (or rather the index of the maximum) out of the predicted moves and use the respective result which I then want to maximize.
I tried to implement this in the following way:

```
move = tf.argmax(output_layer, axis=0)
costl = y_true[0, :]
cost = - tf.gather(y_true, move)
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost)
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I get the following error:
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

How can I achieve a somewhat similar cost function?

Comment: Can you provide more code for a minimal reproducible example?